# Create a program that takes a parameter a two-dimensional list of integers and returns True if each row of the table sums up to an odd number

Tags: python-3.x

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As you can see from what I have so far, my knowledge of the python language is...well...weak.

example:

```
oddrow([[1, 2], [9, 4], [7, 6]])
True

def oddrow(lst):
  for item in lst:
    if sum(item[0:n]) #lost
```

Comment: Are we to understand that your `oddrow` function should return True if the sum of all sub-lists is odd?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`all`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#all) built-in:

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

So a list comprehension can map the *oddness* of the sum of the elements of one inner list into boolean space - e.g. the result for `[[1, 2], [9, 4], [7, 6]]` would look like `[True, True, True]`. And `all` will do the rest.

```py
def oddrow(lst): 
    return all([ sum(l) % 2 == 1 for l in lst ])

# since it's short, why not just make it a one-liner
oddrow = lambda lst: all([ sum(l) % 2 == 1 for l in lst ])
```

Comment: [ expr(x) for x in lst ] is a list comprehension, btw. Basically a for loop that creates a new list, but read the docs for to understand.

Comment: No, I was just explaining what it was. (This before your edit, or maybe I didn't notice)

Comment: @miku Thanks for the explanation, it has helped immensely.